# Re-Applying Course Completion Criteria

Tags: moodle

I have a course that has been completed by a number of users. I would like to reduce the number of activities that are required to be completed for the course to be deemed complete. When I unlock the course completion settings and uncheck the activity and re-apply the course completion criteria, everyone's course completion turns to incomplete. How do I re-apply the new course completion criteria to all those users who have already completed the course?

Comment: Hi - Is there anything else added/removed to the new course completion criteria besides removal of the activity mentioned?

Comment: Just the removal of the one activity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe even if you modify the course completion criteria to less activities, once your cronjob (scheduled tasks) runs the completion will be stored for the users that previously had the completion.

e.g.

- Initial course completion criteria: A, B and C activities.
- Users: 123
  and 456 completed A, B and C activities.
- New course completion
  criteria: A and B, hence the completion records for the course will
  be removed and recalculated in the next cronjob (Moodle scheduled
  tasks) run.

Comment: I believed the same. I even manually executed the cron job with no success.